# how to get standardised (Beta) coefficients for multiple linear regression using statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels, coefficients

when using the `.summary()` function using pandas statsmodels, the OLS Regression Results include the following fields.

```
coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
```

How can I get the standardised coefficients (which exclude the intercept), similarly to what is achievable in SPSS?

Answer (score 12):

You just need to standardize your original DataFrame using a z distribution (i.e., z-score) first and then perform a linear regression.

Assume you name your dataframe as `df`, which has independent variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`, and dependent variable `y`. Consider the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# standardizing dataframe
df_z = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).dropna().apply(stats.zscore)

# fitting regression
formula = 'y ~ x1 + x2 + x3'
result = smf.ols(formula, data=df_z).fit()

# checking results
result.summary()
```

Now, the `coef` will show you the standardized (beta) coefficients so that you can compare their influence on your dependent variable.

Notes:

1. Please keep in mind that you need `.dropna()`. Otherwise, `stats.zscore` will return all `NaN` for a column if it has any missing values.
2. Instead of using `.select_dtypes()`, you can select column manually but make sure all the columns you selected are numeric.
3. If you only care about the standardized (beta) coefficients, you can also use `result.params` to return it only. It will usually be displayed in a scientific-notation fashion. You can use something like `round(result.params, 5)` to round them.

Answer (score 1):

We can just transform the estimated `params` by the standard deviation of the exog. results.t_test(transformation) computes the parameter table for the linearly transformed variables.

AFAIR, the following should produce the beta coefficients and corresponding inferential statistics.

Compute standard deviation, but set it to 1 for the constant.

```
std = model.exog.std(0)
std[0] = 1
```

Then use results.t_test and look at the params_table. `np.diag(std)` creates a diagonal matrix that transforms the `params`.

```
tt = results.t_test(np.diag(std))
print(tt.summary()
tt.summary_frame()
```

Comment: what is the "model" here?

Comment: `model` is any of the model instances, e.g. OLS or GLM. `results` is the corresponding Results instance returned by `model.fit()`. e.g. `model = OLS(y, x)` and `results = model.fit()`

Comment: di you standardize the response variable too>

Comment: my mistake< the usual definition for linear model standardizes also y https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3857#issuecomment-463346200

Answer (score 0):

you can convert unstandardized coefficients by taking std deviation.  Standardized Coefficient (Beta) is the requirement for the driver analysis. Below is the code that works for me.
X is independent variables and y is dependent variable and coefficients are coef which are extracted by (model.params) from ols.

```
sd_x = X.std()
sd_y = Y.std()
beta_coefficients = []

# Iterate through independent variables and calculate beta coefficients
for i, col in enumerate(X.columns):
    beta = coefficients[i] * (sd_x[col] / sd_y)
    beta_coefficients.append([col, beta])

# Print beta coefficients
for var, beta in beta_coefficients:
    print(f' {var}: {beta}')
```